# Android Restricted Permissions

Tags: android, permissions

Recently one of my apps was removed from Google Play store with a reason that I am using one of the restricted permissions. I am not using any of the CALL_LOG or SMS related permissions. Following is the list of permissions that I am requesting.

```
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CALL_PHONE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='com.android.vending.BILLING'
uses-permission: name='com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.BLUETOOTH'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
```

Can anybody help me with what am I missing here? Which is the permission that Google is finding in violation?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not actually using any type of permissions **CALL_LOG or SMS**??? Check once your runtime permissions as well

Comment: Yes, I did a grep/find across the whole directory looking for checkSelfPermission, nothing apart from what si listed above.

Comment: Check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview
and **CALL_PHONE** is kind of dangerous permission

Comment: You can use `Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);` to dial a number from your app and have to remove **CALL_PHONE** permission from your app and upload your app after making changes that I mentioned then you will not get that type of warning.

Comment: Removed CALL_PHONE and call to ACTION_CALL. Still get same error.

Comment: They must have listed in email those permissions that are dangerous in your app. Can you update the question with that context sent in the mail from Google

Comment: In email, nothing is mentioned, but when I try to upload a new version I am seeing `New permissions requests (1 permission) android.permission.READ_SMS`. I don't have this permission anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188863/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-and-vinay-avasthi).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally figured it out. Once you are flagged by Google, you can just not fix the permissions and upload the app. You have first take exception approval by uploading the next version and then upload another version to fix the problem.